# 2nd call to Device.Reset in DirectX throws an InvalidCallException

Tags: c#, .net, directx

I've been working on a DirectX application in C#, and I noticed that when I lock the workstation, the DirectX "Device" becomes lost. After looking up the information about what to do upon when a device is lost (and when a `DeviceLostException` is thrown by `Device.Present`), I re-wrote the code to reset the `Device`. This simply meant that I made a call to `Device.Reset`.

Calling `Device.Reset` recovered the `Device`. No problem. But when I lost the device a second time (for example, when the computer was locked, went to sleep, or activated a screen-saver), an exception was thrown by `Device.Reset`.

The exception was `InvalidCallException`, which (according to the documentation) means something went wrong with the call. So I assumed it was a problem with the arguments to the function. So instead of passing the same copy of `PresentParams` that I used to create the Device, I created a new instance of PresentParams (at first using the copy constructor, and later by re-creating without it) and passed that to `Device.Reset`.

Doesn't work. `Device.Reset` still dies with the `InvalidCallException`. Oh, and the message of the exception? "Error in application." Not helpful.

Can you point me in the direction of either a solution, or some documentation about how to get more debug information out of DirectX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I know how silly is seems to answer my own question, but I figured someone else might need this, eh?

The **answer is**: there were too many calls to the `Dispose` method of the `VertexBuffer`s in the scene. The reason being that the internal `Device` reset-handlers were calling the `Dispose` method. And why was that happening? Because I had neglected to read the .NET DirectX SDK documentation regarding the Pool Enumeration, and was allocating the `VertexBuffer`s using `Pool.Default` instead of `Pool.Managed`.

So obviously, after a few thousand badly done allocate-and-release cycles, something went wrong.

*Oh, and how did I discover this? I attached a listener to `VertexBuffer.Dispose` which incremented a counter that I displayed on-screen. Imagine my suprise when I noticed this counter kept growing as I resized the window!*

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, this saved me a major headache! +1

Comment: Didn't actually solve my problem but +1 for taking the time to share your solution, thank you.